# How to measure the total size of a fastq file in base pairs?

Tags: fastq, bash

Or Kbps/Gbps. It feels like it should be conceptually very simple, but I can't seem to figure out the right combination of keywords to find it via my search engine. Help would be appreciated!

I have BBMAP, SRAtoolkit and MEGAHIT already installed, and also use bash. I'd be very happy if this can be answered with software that I already have, but if not that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using this:

`cat file.fastq | paste - - - - | cut -f 2 | tr -d '\n' | wc -c`

Explanation :

- `paste - - - -` : print four consecutive lines in one row (tab delimited), to merge the info for each read
- `cut -f2` : print only the second column, to access the sequence after the paste
- `wc -c` : count the characters
- `tr -d '\n'`: to remove from count the eventual newline characters

(a tip for your googling: try search for "counting number of bases in fastq file")

Answer (score 1):

The number of bases in a fastq file can be counted in bash with awk and wc

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 0' ORS="" fastqfile|wc -m
```

The awk code prints every fourth line (which is actually the quality scores, but that doesn't matter here). wc -m returns the total number of characters.

Edited to add ORS="" to prevent count of newlines (the double quotes are not strictly required)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Perl:**
Print the sequence lines (line number 2, 6, 10, etc). Remove the newlines with `chomp`. Count the bytes (here, bases) using `wc -c`:

```
perl -ne 'if ( $. % 4 == 2 ) { chomp; print; }' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a fastq parser in Python (for instance the one provided by `mappy`), it is rather straightforward to compute the sum of the lengths of the sequences present in a fastq file:

```
$ python3 -m pip install mappy  # Only if mappy is not installed yet
$ python3 -c 'from mappy import fastx_read; print(sum(len(seq) for (_, seq, *_) in fastx_read("SRR077487_2.filt.fastq.gz")))'
2386161200
```

`python3 -c '<insert some python code here>'` uses the `-c` option of `python3` that tells Python to execute the provided code (instead of starting an interactive interpreter, or running code present in a file).
Here the code has two steps (separated by a `;`, in a standard script, we could use a new line instead): first making the `fastx_read` function available (because it is part of an optional module), second displaying the total length of the sequences.

`fastx_read("path_to_a_file")` generates (name, sequence, quality) triplets when a fastq file is provided, or (name, sequence) pairs when a fasta file is provided.

The `(_, seq, *_)` syntax is a form of "tuple unpacking" where we store the second element (the sequence) in a `seq` variable.
The `_` in is just a way to ignore the first element in the triplet/pair. The `*_` is a way to ignore whatever is after the second element in the triplet/pair.

`len(seq) for (_, seq, *_) in fastx_read("SRR077487_2.filt.fastq.gz")` is an expression representing the lengths (obtained with the predefined `len` function) of the sequences present in the file `"SRR077487_2.filt.fastq.gz"`.

So the code uses the predefined `sum` function to compute the sum of values that are the lengths of the sequences extracted from the fastq file, and this is displayed using the `print` function.

This should also work with either fasta or fastq format, and with or without gz compression.

I tested more parsers on a slightly different problem here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/380/292 and you can find inspiration with the other approaches proposed in the other answers there.

Answer (score 1):

`seqkit stats fastq.gz`. Get SeqKit from https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/

Answer (score 0):

With bbmap:

`reformat.sh </path/to/fastq>`